# Topology induced by lexicographical order is not discret

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, order-theory

> Let $\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}$ be equipped with the lexicographical order. Let $\tau_{LO}$ be the topology regarding the lexicographical order on $\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}$. Show that $\tau_{LO}$ is not discret.

To show that $\tau_{LO}$ is not discret it is enough to give $U\in\mathcal{P}(\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N})$ with $U\notin\tau_{LO}$.

The lexicographical order $<$ is defined as follows:

$u=(u_1,u_2)<(v_1,v_2)=v\iff\begin{cases}u_1<v_1~\text{or}\\u_1=v_1~\text{and} ~u_2<v_2\end{cases}$

A base of the order topology is given by:

$\mathcal{O}=\{(u,v)|u,v\in X, u<v\}\cup\{(-\infty, u), (u,\infty)|u\in X\}\cup\{X\}$.

So there is a set, which can not be written as union of sets in $\mathcal{O}$.

Such a set is $\{(1,0)\}\in\mathcal{P}(\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N})$.

So an interval $(u,v)$ with $u,v\in\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}$ which contains the tupel $(1,0)$ [not the interval] always has other elements and is never a singleton.

Suppose there are such $u,v$. Then $u<(1,0)<v$.

Hence $u_1<1$ or $u_1=1$ and $u_2<0$. Obviously the seconds case does not hold. So $u_1=0$.
The successor of $(1,0)$ is obviously $v=(1,1)$.

So we have $(0,u_2)<(1,0)<(1,1)$ and how ever you choose $u_2$ there will always be infinite many other tupel 'between' $(0,u_2)$ and $(1,0)$.

In other words: A set containing $(1,0)$ can never be open, because $(1,0)$ has no unique predecessor.

And of course this shows explicit that $\{(1,0)\}$ is not open. So $\tau_{LO}$ is not the discret topology.

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof is correct but one of your off-hand comments is wrong: sets containing $(1, 0)$ can be open e.g. $(1, 0) \in \Big((0,42), (1, 1)\Big)$. **Correction:** However yes, sets containing $(1, 0)$ *as its least element* cannot be open.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was the point I was unsure about. Also I misphrased it a little bit. But it is everything clear now.

Comment: Notice that that space is homeomorphic to $\omega_0 + \omega_0$.

Comment: Correct.... If $<$ is a linear order on a set $X$, and $x\in X$ such that  $\min X\ne x=\sup \{y: y<x\}$ then in the order topology, $x$ is in the closure of $\{y:y<x\}.$

Comment: The lex.-ordered space $\{0,1\} \times \Bbb N$ is homeomorphic to the real subspace $\{1-1/n: n\in \Bbb N\}\cup \{2-1/n: n\in \Bbb N\}.$  E.g.for $j\in\{0,1\}$ and $n\in \Bbb N$ let $f(\,(j,n)\,)=1+j-1/n.$